# Query took 5000 seconds but still failed to execute

Tags: mysql

I have run this query into my local data base and it execute within one minute:

```
DELETE sp FROM switch_person sp
INNER JOIN switch_person sp2
WHERE sp.PK < sp2.PK
AND sp.EmployeeNamePK   = sp2.EmployeeNamePK
AND sp.SwitchDate       = sp2.SwitchDate
AND sp.Half             = sp2.Half
```

But after running this query into live server, it is even failed after 5000 seconds. The error was after 5000 seconds  `lock wait timeout exceeded`. I think the server is live and people are making transaction that creating any deadlock. So i just turned off the live hosting but still it taking time and it is continuously running.

I don't think it is related to index issue as I have successfully run this query into my local server where no index is defined into any field.

[image]

**Update:**
Even after putting offline the server around 30 mins my query still running and I hope it will provide **lock wait timeout exceed error after 5000 seconds** as i have also configure mysql like this:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000; 
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000;
```

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table with just the rows you wish to retain, and then delete the old table, and then rename the new table.

Comment: @Strawberry as OP suggested that it is live server with data getting inserted continuously; it gets much difficult to handle the delta changes that happened to the table during the new table creation process.

Comment: I have updated the question with table structure.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan Also, besides defining the index as mentioned above, run the query in batches. Basically delete only 1000 rows at a time, and continue running it until all the rows are deleted. Add a `LIMIT 1000` to the end of the query.

Comment: There are less than 1000 record which will be deleted.

Comment: But actually total records are  around 361,460 total

Comment: I have no index currently. as you can see the image.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya command for indexing?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yeah it worked within one seconds.:) But do i drop index again. ? Next after deleting the duplicate records i am setting composite primary key like this (Alter table switch_person drop primary key, add primary key(EmployeeNamePK,Half,SwitchDate)) but it showing me this error  Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks half of the problem resolved you may answer with proper explanation. i am amazed that why it works after adding index while working correctly on local server without indexing.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan it worked on your local server, because you dont have a load of production where concurrent sessions/users are accessing data. On your local server, MySQL would still be doing complete Table Scan, although with no concurrent load.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need the following Composite index on `switch_person` table. Note that you have a Range condition on the `PK` column during the Join operation, so you will need to keep that column at the end of the index. Define the index as follows:

```
Alter Table switch_person Add Index (EmployeeNamePK, SwitchDate, Half, PK);
```

Afterwards, you can execute your `Delete` query. In case, the Delete operation is going to lead to deletion of 1000s of rows, you can consider doing it in batches. Basically, delete only 1000 rows at a time, and continue running it until all the rows are deleted. Add a `LIMIT 1000` to the end of the `DELETE ..` query.

Once you have finished the delete operation(s), you can `DROP` the index (just now defined one).